# How to use Copyscape API To Check Balance in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am new in VB.NET and recently started learning about programming. My question is how can i add Copyscape API key in vb.net application.

This is the actual URL - http://www.copyscape.com/api-guide.php#balance

When user add their username and password and click test, it should shows the remaining credits in the account.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the guide, you need to read and parse the response from a request to Copyscape's API.

Build the URL according to the documentation, inserting the username taken from a form input where necessary.

The following article explains what to do next once you have the URL ready:

"How to read XML data from a URL by using Visual Basic .NET"
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301232